# Creating a fanchart plot in the fanplot package

Tags: r

I am trying to replicate the Bank of England Fanplot using code from (https://gjabel.wordpress.com/category/r/fanplot/). I'm trying to take his approach to solving it, however for some reason I seem to go wrong with the actual plot. Hoping to find some assistance from someone who can let me know what I'm doing wrong

Here is a reproductible of my initial dataset `data.ts`

```
structure(c(4.6049904235401, 4.60711076016453, 4.60980084146652, 
4.61025389170935, 4.60544515681515, 4.60889021700954, 4.60983993107244, 
4.61091608826696, 4.61138799159174, 4.61294431148318, 4.61167545843765, 
4.61208284263432, 4.61421991328081, 4.61530485425155, 4.61471465043043, 
4.6155992084451, 4.61195799200607, 4.61178486640435, 4.61037927954796, 
4.60744590947049, 4.59979957741728, 4.59948551500254, 4.60078678080182, 
4.60556092645471, 4.60934962087565, 4.60981147563749, 4.61060477704678, 
4.61158365084251, 4.60963435263623, 4.61018215733317, 4.61209710959768, 
4.61231368335184, 4.61071363571141, 4.61019496497916, 4.60948652606191, 
4.61068813487859, 4.6084092003352, 4.60972706132393, 4.60866915174087, 
4.61192565195909, 4.60878767339377, 4.61341471281265, 4.61015272152397, 
4.6093479714315, 4.60750965935653, 4.60768790690338, 4.60676463096309, 
4.60746490411374, 4.60885670935448, 4.60686846708382, 4.60688947889575, 
4.60867708110485, 4.60448791268212, 4.60387348166032, 4.60569806689426, 
4.6069320880709, 4.6087143894128, 4.61059688801283, 4.61065399116698, 
4.61071421014339), .Tsp = c(2004, 2018.75, 4), class = "ts")
```

and here is my application of the author's code

```
library(forecast)
library(fanplot)
library(tidyverse)
library(tsbox)

# Create an ARIMA Model using the auto.arima function

model <- auto.arima(data.ts)

# Simulate forecasts for 8 quarters (2 years) ahead

forecasts <- simulate(model, n=8)

# Create a data frame in a similar way to the boe table 


table <- ts_df(forecasts) %>% 
  rename(mode=value) %>% 
  mutate(time0 = rep(2019,8)) %>% 
  mutate(uncertainty = sd(mode)) %>% 
  mutate(skew = rep(0,8))

y0 <- 2019
k <- nrow(table)

# Set Percentiles 

p <- seq(0.05, 0.95, 0.05)
p <- c(0.01, p, 0.99)

# Simulate a qsplitnorm distribution

fsval <- matrix(NA, nrow = length(p), ncol = k)
for (i in 1:k) 
  fsval[, i] <- qsplitnorm(p, mode = table$mode[i], 
                            sd = table$uncertainty[i],
                            skew = table$skew[i])

# Create Plot

plot(data.ts, type = "l", col = "tomato", lwd = 2, 
     xlim = c(y0 - 2,y0 + 2), ylim = c(4, 5), 
     xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", ylab="")

rect(y0 - 0.25, par("usr")[3] - 1, y0 + 2, par("usr")[4] + 1, 
     border = "gray90", col = "gray90")


fan(data = fsval, data.type = "values", probs = p, 
    start = y0, frequency = 4, 
    anchor = data.ts[time(data.ts) == y0 - 0.25], 
    fan.col = colorRampPalette(c("tomato", "gray90")),  
    ln = NULL, rlab = NULL)
```

I think I have done everything correctly up until the plot creation (and things go horribly wrong from there), so I'm just hoping that someone can spot my error

Comment: your code does not replicate... which package is `ts_data.frame` from? what is `p`?

Comment: Hi @guyabel. Apologies I was using the ```tsbox``` package to convert my forecasts to a dataframe and I forgot to add the specification on percentiles ```p```. I have edited the post

Comment: i think the code is all good except for the `ylim` in the `plot()` function. it is far too wide so the data appears as a straight line and the fan is almost invisible. try setting `ylim = range(fsval, data.ts)` ... hopefully this works?

Comment: Thank you @guyabel, yes that worked! Much appreciated